# meaning of negotiate your way out of

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can you tell me the meaning of "negotiate your way out ....."
I saw a phrase related to that in the following article:

https://www.politico.com/story/2018/05/21/trump-phone-security-risk-hackers-601903

In this article : " It’s baffling that Trump isn’t taking baseline cybersecurity measures at a time when he is trying to negotiate his way out of a trade war with China, a country that is known for using cyber tactics to gain the upper hand in business negotiations,”.

Please help me ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It means.. ‘to get out pf it by talking’. Rather than by launching missiles and creating wars, to sit around a table, have a discussion, and reach  an agreement.

The opposite might be to ‘fight one’s way out of it’.